# HTML/CSS Website conversion to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, html, document-converter, conversion

This is my first time ever working with SharePoint I have developed websites before PHP/Ruby but I have never worked with this before. I have SP Designer installed but I'm really clueless how to get around.

I have a simple HTML websites (5-static) pages with a personal design (css). I would like to deploy this website to my sharepoint site So far I have this done I uploaded my html files renamed to aspx but I lost all the options to edit pages and add new content etc.

Is there an easy way I can convert my template into a sharepoint master page/template and then recreate all of my 5 pages with sharepoint ?

If not is there a simple way I can just plug in to my existing pages a container of sorts say define area from where to where content can be edited ?

I followed the MSDN tutorial but I got stuck unable to find the option to edit a master page. I went to read further but I don't understand most of the ASP content.

Comment: Not really an answer, but would relate with working in SP you need to think of designing your pages as SP pages and not regular web pages. If you don't, why use SP in the first place. You could be fat/dumb/happy just sticking with html/css. You can use SP to create regular html content, but IMHO you should make these types of pages sparse.

Comment: Are you using 2013? If so have you looked at [Design Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx)? It can convert HTML-pages to Masterpages including your CSS (need some custom markup)

Answer (score 1):

@ericb has you on the right track.  If you are using O365 or have enterprise level client access license for on premise deployment then design manager may be the quickest way.   You can do a search for "getting started with design manager" and get tons of resources.  Microsoft Technet / MSDN has really good articles as well as some videos.  Design manager will allow you to use HTML markup that gets converted to a SharePoint master page.  There are pre-defined 'snippets' that allow you add back SharePoint items like search box, Title Icon, etc.

Now if you don't have access to Design manager you can still create your own custom Master pages. I recommend you search for "Randy Drisgill" as well as TechNet/MSDN references for going down this path.

For your content - after you have the MasterPage configured you would create traditional pages via the SharePoint interface.  Again - if you have Design manager you create custom layout pages fairly easy - but if not you will need to either use the included layouts available or manually create your own.

As much as Microsoft has done to try and make this easier there is still a small ramp up required for creating MasterPages, Layouts, and traditional pages.

You may also want to consider PluralSight as a training reference.  There is a ton of videos on SharePoint and branding available.